# Postfix will not send emails

Tags: postfix

About 8 Month ago, my postfix worked, now it does not work, does my log file look ok?

```
Aug 21 17:00:34 localhost postfix/master[9342]: daemon started -- version 2.7.0, configuration /etc/postfix
Aug 21 17:01:11 localhost postfix/smtpd[9354]: connect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Aug 21 17:01:11 localhost postfix/smtpd[9354]: C691694D4F: client=localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Aug 21 17:01:11 localhost postfix/cleanup[9358]: C691694D4F: message-id=<52152a97a19ea_1f7542665f21564a@li534-212.mail>
Aug 21 17:01:11 localhost postfix/qmgr[9345]: C691694D4F: from=<administrator@mcmdacm.com>, size=746, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug 21 17:01:11 localhost postfix/smtpd[9354]: disconnect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Aug 21 17:01:12 localhost postfix/smtp[9359]: C691694D4F: to=<xxxxx.yyyyy@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.68.26]:25, delay=0.35, delays=0.05/0.01/0.12/0.16, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1377118871 f10si5584777qai.16 - gsmtp)
Aug 21 17:01:12 localhost postfix/qmgr[9345]: C691694D4F: removed
```

(Note:  I changed actual email to: xxxxx.yyyyy@gmail.com)

I did some tracing, results below

```
$ host -t A smtp.gmail.com
smtp.gmail.com is an alias for gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com.
gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com has address 173.194.68.108
gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com has address 173.194.68.109

$ host -t MX gmail.com
gmail.com mail is handled by 30 alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com mail is handled by 10 alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com mail is handled by 40 alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com mail is handled by 5 gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com mail is handled by 20 alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
$
```

I am pretty new to email, so is it possible that I was black-listed somewhere by any chance?

Edit 8/22/13:
OK, got the answer, email can be sent, but email servers will reject it unless criteria is filled, see the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12891184/setup-devise-user-confirmation-to-all-responding-to-emails-rather-than-clicking)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that logfile looks absolutely honkey-dorey. Your mail is being sent to the gmail MX'es. Maybe it simply ended up in the spam box?

Comment: Thank you, checked multiple destination emails (my work email and my gmail), seems like I cannot send emails.  What can I do to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Find the logmessage of an actual failure to send and post that.

Comment: Well, I posted the log I know of, would you suggest logs to view?

Comment: If that's all the log you have, I'd love to know what you base your conclusion on, as the log clearly shows the mail is delivered to gmail.

Comment: Well I am new to this, so I probably do not sound very intelligent, but my co-worker tried to use my web application, I got the same log, but the email did not go through for her either.  So is it possible that google is not liking me?

Comment: OK, you are absolutely right, it did go to spam folder,

Comment: Just sending email does not work, the following link provided me with good guidence. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12891184/setup-devise-user-confirmation-to-all-responding-to-emails-rather-than-clicking)